# HTML/CSS - Google Font Fira Sans rendering

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-webfonts

My page designer sent me his work including Fira Sans google font. So I have a bad rendering on my laptop, and on my pc in the office.. but it's good in my pc at home.

All have installed Windows 7. I'll show you the screens from google fonts webpage.

This is the rendering in Firefox:

[image: This is the rendering in Firefox]

No matter if I use @font-face or @import or I add it in a `<head>` tag.. results are always the same. So I wonder if I have it on 2 out of 3 machines.. what about other users. Should I quit this font?

Did anyone else experienced something like this before?

UPDATE:
This is the rendering from Joel's snippet
[image: Joel's snippet]

Comment: this rendering of my snippet is on chrome or moz?

Comment: its on moz.. on chrome nothing is visible

Comment: i'm running it on chrome (i usually use chrome) and i don't see nothing wrong... :/

Comment: ok here is a link of my chrome view.. as you can see i can select the text and copy it, but can't see it:

http://imgur.com/a/U2dsa

Answer (score 0):

You must load it as link rel.

```css
*{font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;}
.bold{font-weight:bold;}
.italic{font-style: italic;}
.oblique{font-style: oblique;}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<p><span class="bold">when you import a font </span> by CDN it will be loaded in client side on page loads, so no matters what device is loading it. Maybe you are <span class="italic">not linking it well</span> or you're working on local machine or <span class="oblique">localhost and it</span> causes some issues. On a server must work fine.</p>
```

**EDIT**
Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: its not about loading it on my page.. I think its more about the font itself.. My screenshots are showing the google fonts page.. just check them

Comment: obviously, the render engine of each browser will load different, sometimes we cannot appreciate it, other times are too different... We cannot do nothing on there, sorry. Send an angry e-mail to moz developers :P

Comment: yes, i also can see all good renderings on many browsers.. we have 4 pcs and 5 laptops in our setup.. but 2 laptops and 2 pcs show bad rendering..

Comment: then upgrade your browsers... huh? :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the same font from mozilla cdn.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.cdn.mozilla.net/fonts/fira.css">
```

it works great also on other browsers. I've also found out that Google Fonts team is still working on Fira Font, so until then I'll be sticking to mozilla version.

For @font-face you can download the package from github
https://github.com/mozilla/Fira/releases/tag/4.202